# when storing a value in swift 3, how do i first check if something is already stored with the same forKey?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

if i wanted to locally store a value in a swift app in xcode like this:

```
   let name = "john doe"
   UserDefaults.standard.set(name , forKey: "User Name")
```

how would I test to see if there is already saved under that key in order to avoid saving the same thing twice or saving two things under the same key? is there a .doesExist sort of function the way theres a .isEmpty?

Comment: You don't test. If there is something there, you are replacing it. It's your key, so it's your info; you can't go wrong. But note that UserDefaults is not "local" storage. It is _persistent_ storage; don't use it unless you need that.

Comment: FYI - you can only store one value per key just like any dictionary. Of course that one thing can be an array if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object(forKey:)` to determine if any value is stored for a given key - it will return `nil` if there is no object stored for that key.

If you use any of the `set` functions then the current value (if any) for that key is replaced.  It isn't possible for there to be two things saved under the one key.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if never define in specific key.

```
let newUserName = "john doe"
//check if already stored
if  let oldUsername = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "User_Name") 
{
   //set new value of "User_Name" here
   print("\(oldUsername)")
} else {
   // set value of "User_Name" here
   UserDefaults.standard.set(newUserName , forKey: "User_Name")
}
```